# Cannot sync contacts from Google

Tags: motorola-moto-g, 5.1-lollipop

My Moto G 1st gen running on Lollipop does not want to aggregate Google contacts from my `contact.google.com` list. The Contacts app does not allow me to import contacts from Google account. It also does not recognize the Google account in the `Contacts > Menu > Accounts` - I can see Facebook account and Skype account, but not the Google account (even when it is visible in the `Settings > Accounts`).

I cannot add any new account. When I click on the "Add account", it gives me the possibility to choose 2 "Exchange" accounts with the Gmail icon, but for both of them, when clicked, it says that there is already a Google account on the device.

- I have tried to reinstall with no Facebook account introduced, does not work
- I have tried to pass via Google+, it imported the contacts from Google+ without the phone numbers.
- I have restored the SMS (backed up previously from my phone) and it does not recognize the sender (only the numbers),
- It does recognize some of the callers, but it still asks whether to add them to contacts, so most probably it is not from my Google contacts.
- reinstalls, reboots, reformat - all done.

Do you have any ideas?